# HTML and Angular: Select depends on other select

Tags: javascript, html, angular

i have a litte question about angular. i have these two select-fields and i would like to filter the result
of the second select-field with the selected option of the first select-field. A1 and A2 are only text. A secObj is
also text. So if A1 is selected first, in select-field 2 all models with modelname A2 should be in the result.

i tried many sources of the internet but nothing worked.

thank you!

```
<div class="test">
       <select class="form-control" name="testA" id="123">
            <option>A1</option>
            <option>A2</option>
        </select> </div>

<div class="test2">

    <select class="form-control" name="testB" id="456">

        <option *ngFor="let model of models| filter: {modelname: ?? A1. or A2 ??} ;trackBy: trackId "> {{model.id}}

    </option>

</select></div>
```

Comment: Could you just post how your `models` array looks like?

Answer (score 1):

```js
angular.module('myApp', [])
    .controller('myCtrl', ['$scope', function($scope) {
      $scope.item = ['A1','A2','A3']
       $scope.selected_item = 'A1'
      $scope.sub_item = {'A1':[1,2,3,4,5],'A2':[4,5,6],'A3':[5,7,8]}
  $scope.slected_sub_item = $scope.sub_item[$scope.selected_item]
  $scope.selected_sub_item_selected = $scope.slected_sub_item[0]
      $scope.update= function(key) {
         $scope.selected_item =  key;
   $scope.slected_sub_item = $scope.sub_item[$scope.selected_item]
   $scope.selected_sub_item_selected = $scope.slected_sub_item[0]
   
      };
    }]);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<body ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">
<select ng-options="val for val in item" ng-change="update(selected_item)" ng-model="selected_item"></select>
<select ng-options="val for val in slected_sub_item" ng-model="selected_sub_item_selected"></select>
</body>
```

Comment: Thank you. is it possible to do it easier?

Comment: Play with Object..it will simplify more work..this is the easier way

Comment: I thought the OP posted a template which looks like it’s Angular 2+